# Loop over text file to find and replace a line using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file ... 'datarcTemp'

```
0 data/srdata
1 data/my.dat
2 data/alp1.dat
3 data/ba.dat
```

I want to find 'alp1.dat' and replace it with 'alp2.dat'
I am using for loop to find it, but it is not working. Any ideas ??

```
set x=2
set y= data/alp1.dat
set line=%x%%y%

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (datarcTemp) do (
if %%a=="%line%" echo line found
set /a count+=1
rem counting all lines
)
```

Comment: As the doublequotes form part of the string, you should be using `if "%%a"=="%line%"`, not `if %%a=="%line%"`.

Comment: Can you help me to replace 'alp1.dat' with 'alp2.dat' ?

Comment: use [substring substitution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) and don't forget [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

Comment: Where do you want to replace? Your code does not output anything except `line found`...

Comment: @Stephan - It is just to rename the variable, not to replace the string in file.

Comment: @aschipfl - Yes .. I trying to figure out. How can I replace it ..couldn't found yet

Comment: `set "string=!string:search=replace!"`

Comment: @Stephan - It doesn't help. you are replacing the string alone. I have to edit the file

Comment: read the file line by line, replace the string and write it to a new file. When done, you can change the name back to the original file's.

Comment: @alpha, if 'It is just to rename the variable, not to replace the string in file', then you could try `If /I "%%a"=="%line%" Set "line=%x%%y:1=2%"&Echo line found`.